# RDA data argument is of the wrong type

Tags: r, rda

I am performing a redundancy analysis in RStudio. My data includes several environmental variables as the community data matrix, and a GROUP column, which is the constraining matrix. For example:

```
CONDUCTIVITY    pH    GROUP
453            7.5    A
462            7.7    A
500            8.1    B
525            8.0    B
308            8.4    C
306            8.5    C
```

I am doing a redundancy analysis to compare the environmental variables between groups (which represent locations), such as, is the conductivity in group A significantly different than the conductivity in group B. My R script is as follows:

```
df <- read.csv("All_data_long_format.csv")

library(vegan)

rda <- rda(df[,2:9] ~ df$GROUP) # columns 2 to 9 are the environmental variables
```

I get the error:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula,"Condition",data=data): 'data' argument is of the wrong type.
```

I'm not sure what this means, but my guess is 'df' is the wrong type, but I'm not sure why or how to solve it.

Comment: if you run `str(df)` on your data, it will tell you whether or not it is a data frame. If it is, unless rda was designed to work on a specific class of object in r, the function should probably work.  In looking at the data here, you have 3 columns, but your code evaluates columns 2 through 9 . against Group, which happens to be column three in this example. If it is also located within the 2:9 range above, then rda is likely not sure how to discriminate against a column included in the analysis

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I have more environmental variables than conductivity and pH, so columns 2 to 9 are these, and column 10 is the group. I didn't show my full table. When i run str(df), the environmental variables show up as numbers. Is this incorrect?